# Running NUnit Tests in parallel using NANT

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, nant, parallel-processing

We have different categories of tests under various assemblies. What is the best possible way to run them in parallel? I am aware of a  task in ant, is there any such task in NANT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, from memory, you need NUnit version 2.5.x or above to run parallel unit tests, which I also remember being a paid-for product.

However, if you use MbUnit, the Gallio test-runner that it comes with runs the tests in parallel and is free.

Either way, you get NAnt to call the unit test runner (either NCover/NUnit or Gallio) and it runs them from there, and not direct from NAnt as this is just a scripting language, but one with significant power to call-out to other processes.

Comment: Ah apologies then - when I was looking into this a while ago, the PUnit stuff was available through 2.5.x but wasn't free. Obviously, since then, things have changed.  Cheers for the update!